# Google map api for hebrew

Tags: google-maps, hebrew

I am developing google map application for Israeli but i have no idea that geocoding not found address location using hebrew name address. I am really need help what should i do to get that.

Issue still exists that related with curl. 
Using browser i get response with Ok status for this : 
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%9C%2053%20%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C&output=json&sensor=true

But using curl google response with Bad Request. Anyone can help?

Thanks,
Dwi

Answer (score 9):

Are you passing the hebrew language parameter when calling the JS file?

> http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Localization

e.g. I think you would do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=iw">
```

Comment: i am already do for that map. i am using geocoding to get address like : הרצל 53 נתניה ישראל, but i can not get return. What should i do to get location latLng for that geocoding. Your help very appreciated and thanks.

Comment: In your geocoder request are you passing the region attribute?

Comment: Hi Ducon, I just recognize of making mistake. I am urlencode the address and makking that not found. I am removing that encoding and working fine. My you have suggestion or idea of what i am doing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Hebrew please add this

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=iw
```

As example for lnaguage hebrew

Comment: The [list of supported languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport) states `iw` for Hebrew