# Googlemaps [gmap], how can I set the language?

Tags: google-maps, localization

I have this line of code: (the preferred language is Hebrew)

```
[gmap width="940" height="350" lat="0" long="0" style="full" zoom="14" marker="yes" infowindow="car wash" infowindowdefault="no" maptype="ROADMAP" hidecontrols="true" address="California"]
```

I tried to use the "language=iw" and "hl=he".

But I can't seem to find the solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `[gmap]` is a WordPress short code tag, didn't realize that till now.

Thanks to Jawad I found that link that contains the Localize parameters:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_countries

The answer to my question is taken from here:
[Google map api for hebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499302/google-map-api-for-hebrew)

I added `&language=iw` to the google maps links and it's done- showing the map in Hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

These Are The Google Supported Languages With Their Identifiers

```
Language    Identifier
Afrikaans   af
Albanian    sq
Basque  eu
Belarusian  be
Bulgarian   bg
Catalan ca
Chinese (Simplified)    zh-cn
Chinese (Traditional)   zh-tw
Croatian    hr
Czech   cs
Danish  da
Dutch   nl
Dutch (Belgium) nl-be
Dutch (Netherlands) nl-nl
English en
English (Australia) en-au
English (Belize)    en-bz
English (Canada)    en-ca
English (Ireland)   en-ie
English (Jamaica)   en-jm
English (New Zealand)   en-nz
English (Phillipines)   en-ph
English (South Africa)  en-za
English (Trinidad)  en-tt
English (United Kingdom)    en-gb
English (United States) en-us
English (Zimbabwe)  en-zw
Estonian    et
Faeroese    fo
Finnish fi
French  fr
French (Belgium)    fr-be
French (Canada) fr-ca
French (France) fr-fr
French (Luxembourg) fr-lu
French (Monaco) fr-mc
French (Switzerland)    fr-ch
Galician    gl
Gaelic  gd
German  de
German (Austria)    de-at
German (Germany)    de-de
German (Liechtenstein)  de-li
German (Luxembourg) de-lu
German (Switzerland)    de-ch
Greek   el
Hawaiian    haw
Hungarian   hu
Icelandic   is
Indonesian  in
Irish   ga
Italian it
Italian (Italy) it-it
Italian (Switzerland)   it-ch
Japanese    ja
Korean  ko
Macedonian  mk
Norwegian   no
Polish  pl
Portuguese  pt
Portuguese (Brazil) pt-br
Portuguese (Portugal)   pt-pt
Romanian    ro
Romanian (Moldova)  ro-mo
Romanian (Romania)  ro-ro
Russian ru
Russian (Moldova)   ru-mo
Russian (Russia)    ru-ru
Serbian sr
Slovak  sk
Slovenian   sl
Spanish es
Spanish (Argentina) es-ar
Spanish (Bolivia)   es-bo
Spanish (Chile) es-cl
Spanish (Colombia)  es-co
Spanish (Costa Rica)    es-cr
Spanish (Dominican Republic)    es-do
Spanish (Ecuador)   es-ec
Spanish (El Salvador)   es-sv
Spanish (Guatemala) es-gt
Spanish (Honduras)  es-hn
Spanish (Mexico)    es-mx
Spanish (Nicaragua) es-ni
Spanish (Panama)    es-pa
Spanish (Paraguay)  es-py
Spanish (Peru)  es-pe
Spanish (Puerto Rico)   es-pr
Spanish (Spain) es-es
Spanish (Uruguay)   es-uy
Spanish (Venezuela) es-ve
Swedish sv
Swedish (Finland)   sv-fi
Swedish (Sweden)    sv-se
Turkish tr
Ukranian    uk
```

Comment: You are saying that there is no support with Hebrew?
like "language=iw" 
, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499302/google-map-api-for-hebrew

Comment: Here are the Geocoding Countries and Supported Languages..
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_countries